# Why doesn't my Perl CGI script compile after I upgrade Perl?

Tags: perl, cgi

After upgrading Perl, I receive some errors in a Perl CGI script:

> Unquoted string "type" may clash with future reserved word at convertit.cgi
>   line 183. Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at convertit.cgi
>   line 183, near ""text/javascript\">flashPreloadFinish
>   ('http://www.myurl.com/mysite.html');\n";"
>   convertit.cgi had compilation errors.

Line 183-184:

```
print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">flashPreloadFinish
('http://www.myurl.com/mysite.html');</script>\n";
print "</body></html>\n";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An earlier line has an unclosed ".

Answer (score 4):

See my [Troubleshooting Perl CGI scripts](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=380424) or [brian's Guide to Solving Any Perl Problem](http://www252.pair.com/comdog/brian's_guide.pod). Both of them take you through the steps to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problems with your code, but I'd suggest rewriting it as

```
print <<'EOT';
<script type="text/javascript">flashPreloadFinish('http://www.myurl.com/mysite.html');</script>
</body></html>
EOT
```